# keyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent() returns RESULT_CANCELEDon Android Q

Tags: android, security, biometrics, keyguard, keyguardlock

I have an application, where I'm requesting user to Authenticate in my app via `KeyguardManager` using **PIN**.

The important thing is that I have `android:showOnLockScreen="true"` to my activity in manifest, so when device is locked, and my activity is showing, I'm tapping on "Sign in" button, which calls `showAuthenticationScreen()`, I'm receiving  `RESULT_CANCELED` in my `onActivityResult()`.

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void showAuthenticationScreen() {
    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    if (keyguardManager == null) {
        return;
    }

    Intent kgIntent = keyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(getString(R.string.nnl_kg_title), getKgPrompt());

    if (kgIntent != null) {
        startActivityForResult(kgIntent, KG_REQUEST_ID);
    }
}
```

I took a look to system logs, and found out that I'm getting this error back from `BiometricService` with message *"Canceling from CDC"*. Here is some part of system logs.

```
936   936 I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.app.action.CONFIRM_DEVICE_CREDENTIAL_WITH_USER flg=0x8080000 pkg=com.android.settings cmp=com.android.settings/.password.ConfirmDeviceCredentialActivity$InternalActivity (has extras)} from
uid 1000
11-11 10:54:53.076   936   972 D ActivityTaskManager: Top Process State changed to PROCESS_STATE_TOP_SLEEPING
11-11 10:54:53.092   936  1032 W ProcessStats: Tracking association SourceState{2c15fa1 com.android.settings/1000 Top #565108} whose proc state 1 is better than process ProcessState{54a9784 com.google.android.gms.persistent/10029 pkg=com.google.android.gms} proc st
ate 2 (9 skipped)
11-11 10:54:53.126   936   936 D BiometricService: Creating auth session. Modality: 1, cookie: 1632337634
11-11 10:54:53.127   936   936 V FingerprintService: startAuthentication(com.android.settings)
11-11 10:54:53.128   936   936 V FingerprintService: Returning cookie: 1632337634
11-11 10:54:53.128   936   936 D BiometricService: Matched cookie: 1632337634, 0 remaining
11-11 10:54:53.128   936   936 V FingerprintService: starting client AuthenticationClientImpl(com.android.settings) cookie: 1632337634/1632337634
11-11 10:54:53.135   936   936 W FingerprintService: client com.android.settings is authenticating...
11-11 10:54:53.161   936   936 D BiometricService: Cancelling from CDC
11-11 10:54:53.162   936   936 V FingerprintService: Stopping client com.android.settings, fromClient: false
11-11 10:54:53.173   936   936 W FingerprintService: client com.android.settings is no longer authenticating
11-11 10:54:53.177   936  3056 D ActivityTaskManager: Top Process State changed to PROCESS_STATE_TOP
11-11 10:54:53.195   936   936 V FingerprintService: handleError(client=com.android.settings, error = 5)
11-11 10:54:53.195   936   936 V FingerprintService: Done with client: com.android.settings
11-11 10:54:53.196   936   936 D BiometricService: Error: 5 cookie: 1632337634
11-11 10:54:53.285   936  3041 I ActivityTaskManager: Activity reported stop, but no longer stopping: ActivityRecord{9b6d8b u0 com.natigbabayev.biometricprompt/.MainActivity t1936}
```

So is there any solution to this? Can I still ask users to authenticate with PIN even when device is locked? 
Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: do u got solution ?

Comment: Nope @JithishPN.

Answer (score -1):

You never used this function -  `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` in your Current Activity

which is used to process the return values from the activity which returns the result codes into the current activity that you are in.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == KG_REQUEST_ID){
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Your Code if Authenticated Successfully.
        }
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Your Code If Canceled.
        }
    }
}
```